# Least count of an instrument and mean absolute error precedence

Tags: error-analysis

My question is, if after repeated measurements the $\delta l$ value i.e. $$\frac{1}{n}\sum^{n} {(x_i-\bar x)^2}$$ comes to be less than Least Count of the instrument used.

$$\delta l \leq L.C.$$
Then would the my measurement be written as $$ l \pm \delta l$$ or $$ l \pm \text{least count value of instrument}$$ ?

Where $l$ is the average of all measurements (without error).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example to help you think about it yourself: suppose you're measuring a stick with a metre scale, and the closest value consistently comes out to be 28.3 cm over 100 measurements. Which do you think makes more sense: that the length of the stick is *exactly* 28.3 cm (all the way down to the atomic scale), or that any variation from 28.3 cm is just *smaller* than the least count of your instrument?

Comment: I get it, the variation that I thus shall obtain would be Mean absolute val. (The value which is not depicted my the instrument because of its limitation but because of repeated measurements I get it through average). Thanks.